# Yaml: structural considerations (map vs list elements)

Tags: list, dictionary, yaml

Are there significant differences in usability between the two options below that I'm overlooking? Pitfalls I should consider?

Each can be addressed easily enough, iterated over, etc.  I feel as though I'm missing something obvious because right now, the only thing I'm seeing is cosmetics.

```
---
db_instances_map:
    DB_01:
        host: db01.example.com
        port: 1521
        user: foo
        pass: bar

    DB_02:
        host: db02.example.com
        port: 1521
        user: foo
        pass: bar


db_instances_list:
    - service_name: DB_01
      host: db01.example.com
      port: 1521
      user: foo
      pass: bar

    - service_name: DB_02
      host: db02.example.com
      port: 1521
      user: foo
      pass: bar
...
```

Edit: It was late when I posted this, but one thing I forgot to acknowledge is address-ability; You don't need to iterate over the map if you know the key, whereas you have to traverse the list to find a known element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first big difference is that you if for any reason the **order** in which your program processes the key-value pairs in the mapping is important, then you might run into trouble, as the YAML standard does not guarantee that program internal order to be the same as the one in the documents. (Some parsers guarantee this order, e.g. my ruamel.yaml in round-trip mode, for others this is not guaranteed explicitly and/or might depend on the version of the library or the version of the language).

The second big difference is that the example using a list is much more easily implemented as tagged object, which you can, and probably should, do to make it explicit that you are loading instances of a database and not generic maps with some values:

```
db_instances_list:
    - !Database
      service_name: DB_01
      host: db01.example.com
      port: 1521
      user: foo
      pass: bar

    - !Database
      service_name: DB_02
      host: db02.example.com
      port: 1521
      user: foo
      pass: bar
```

Doing that is IMO much better than letting someone guess, based on the content of your root level key scalars, that these five key-value pairs are going to be interpreted by your program as attributes (or instantiation values) of a `Database` instance (I am assuming that my interpretation of that key is right).

You can get the same effect using a tag on the key:

```
db_instances_map:
    !Database DB_01:
        host: db01.example.com
        port: 1521
        user: foo
        pass: bar
```

But that is not natively supported in any YAML libraries that I know off, and hence far less recognisable for people using YAML documents.

Comment: It was late when I posted this, but one thing I forgot to acknowledge is address-ability; You don't need to iterate over the map if you know the key, whereas you have to traverse the list to find a known element.

Comment: Also, thank you for the extra bit about tags - they look useful. (I'm just exploring the features of yaml, seems I've been hiding under a rock)

Comment: The addressability is true, one way to go around that is tag the list if `!Database` items as `!Databases` and have some method on there that looks up the database instance based on its service name transparently. In Python e.g. you can then have `__getitem__` be that method and use `databases['DB_01']`